# How to run a JAVA Program without Main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans

This is maybe a bit of a dumb question, but I had this problem now a few times and can't find an answer to it: How do you run a Java program that has no Main class in IntelliJ? There is no "run" button and when I click on Run -> Run in the Menu, it opens a window called "Run" and asks me to provide a main class:

[image]

[image]

I'm actually trying to get the output from my webcam into my Java program and I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s9qqVPQngU
I cloned his project like he shows in the video and then at 1:08 he just right clicks in the NetBeans IDE and clicks on "Run File" and runs the program miraculously without any main class? 
https://github.com/tahaemara/camera-recorder
He doesn't seem to reply on comments on his youtube video...

Comment: in order to run an app, you either have a main method, or it is a service that runs on a server, and is being called by some process (a rest call, for instance). This is likely a library for which you need to provide a main method in the code using it.

Comment: It looks like its build with the build tool ANT, if you look in the `build.xml` you can see it importing a different ant build xml which is found here: https://github.com/tahaemara/camera-recorder/blob/master/nbproject/build-impl.xml 
You need to create run config using the ant build targets described there.

Could be you need to do a lot more cause it looks really old and depended on a lot of external needed to import libraries.

Start with the ANT stuff and follow the errors I guess.

Comment: ok thank you two, I will need to learn more about ANT first and then I will try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Main is the class contains main method, CamRecorder is your main class.
There should have a green triangle before main method, you can click this to run.

Comment: "CamRecorder is your main class" ...
I don't see a main method in any of the posted images, where do you get this information?

Comment: i see the github witch you gave

Answer (score 0):

You have to main method to run your project. for exp. `public static void main(String [] args){}` .

Comment: "You have to main method", not necessarily, as I've already explained in the comments. Considering the question, the OP seems to be aware what a main method is, and how to use it.